# Is One Piece named after Gol D. Roger discovered it?

Tags: one-piece

We know that One Piece is the goal for Luffy to become pirate king, but I want to know about One Piece itself.

Did One Piece named after Gol d. Roger discovered it or its already One Piece when he discovered it?

Comment: I think it should be 'Is One Piece named....'

Comment: @bot well, I'm sorry for poor grammar, English not my main language, still learning. Thanks XD

Comment: F***.. NO OP THIS WEEK..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always believed that he said he left his treasure in "one piece" (which is a phrase that means intact/complete/undamaged/undivided).  As so little is known and that is the only decription, it became the defacto name.

This implies that the popular name was created after Gol's death.

However, the nature of the One Piece treasure and specifically what he meant is not fully clarified yet.  This means we don't know if he said "one piece" (intact) or "One Piece" (name for something or a play on words).

To fully answer this properly if this is a pun, you may need to find the original untranslated wording and someone who understands English and Japanese well.  Alternatively, wait until it is revealed (in several years hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

The whole story wouldn't be if it wasn't for the Gol D. Roger's assurance that he really has his treasure unharmed and out of danger. He let people know that if somebody wants it, he can has it as long as he finds it. It's assumed that it is in the last island,Raftel, (so the "King of Pirates" could only have it I guess) having in mind that he surrendered voluntarily so he could have hidden it anywhere but the most difficult place, is the one that's hard to reach.

From [One Piece](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece)'s wikia page:

> One Piece (ひとつなぎの大秘宝（ワンピース） Wan Pīsu?, kanji read as "Hitotsunagi no Daihihō", **translating to "The Great Treasure of One Piece"**) is a legendary treasure said to be of unimaginable value.

It could be either the treasure itself, or the place that treasure lays. Both occasions leads that One Piece is something that Gol D. Rogger created by gathering his treasure and leaving it somewhere.

So One Piece is just another big treasure (probably the biggest) of the seas, but **Gol D. Roger gave it's name since he is the one who made it**.

Answer (score 0):

One Piece could also refer to the Pony-glyphs, being the Pony-glyphs main piece that connects all the others and makes sense out of all the others.

We know that Roger could read the Pony-glyphs as he signed the bell fry in Skypeia. Robin comes to the understanding that all of these are connected, some with information, some telling the location of the ones with information.

This could mean that One Piece is either a Pony-glyph, one of the great weapons mentioned in the Pony-glyphs, or it could be whatever the person who found it wants it to be.

Comment: I think Poneglyph and One Piece is different at all, because if so, that's mean Luffy's goal and Robin's goal would be the same. Robin's goal is to know the void century that written on Poneglyph, I think it's not gonna be interesting right? Plus no one said that Roger could read the Poneglyph, or maybe not yet said in the anime or manga, I don't remember Rayleigh mention that Roger can read Poneglyph.

Comment: He signs the Poneglyph at Skypeia so the assumption is that he can read them, or someone in his crew can read them.  "It has also been revealed that Gol D. Roger was able to follow the passage because he could hear "the voice of all things", and was able to uncover the path." from One Piece wiki. and skypiea arc, chapter [301] (http://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/301/11)

Comment: I know about that, I mean, it's only assumption right? Just like I said, not yet told in manga or anime that Roger can read the Poneglyph.

Comment: Its assumption that he personally can read it, but someone in his crew if not him, can. It may be entirely the opposite and he can't read them at all, but his ability to 'hear the voice of all things' that gives him the ability to read and write in any language. This is like Luffy talking to the Sea Kings, who only the mermaid princess was able to talk to, and Roger 22 years prior. Luffy's ability being a new found ability meaning he couldn't read the Poneglyph at Alabasta.